# ANT error: failed to create task or type antlib:com.salesforce:deploy

Tags: ant, salesforce, force.com

I've started to play with the Force.com Migration Tool. I want to use it from an ANT build file. I've created this one:

```
<project name="Subversion to Org" default="deploy" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
    <target name="deploy">
        <echo message="deploying from metadata" />
        <echo message="ANT_HOME=${ant.home}"/>
        <echo message="BASEDIR=${basedir}"/>
        <echo message="ANT_CORE_LIB=${ant.core.lib}"/>
        <echo message="JAVA_VERSION=${ant.java.version}"/>
        <echo message="ANT_LIBRARY_DIR=${ant.library.dir}"/>
        <echo message="classpath=${java.class.path}"/>
        <sf:deploy username="${properties.username}"
                        password="${properties.password}"
                        serverurl="${properties.url}"
                        deployroot="${properties.root}"
                        singlePackage="${properties.singlePackage}"
                        runAllTests="${properties.allTest}" />
        </target>
</project>
```

I've copied the ant-salesforce.jar in ant.lib folder. When I execute this file throught ANT  I get this:

```
     Buildfile: build.xml

deploy:
     [echo] deploying from metadata
     [echo] ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
     [echo] BASEDIR=/usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/Salesforce Deploy Test/workspace/deploy script
     [echo] ANT_CORE_LIB=/usr/share/java/ant-1.7.1.jar
     [echo] JAVA_VERSION=1.6
     [echo] ANT_LIBRARY_DIR=/usr/share/ant/lib
     [echo] classpath=/usr/share/java/ant.jar:/usr/share/java/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/java/jaxp_parser_impl.jar:/usr/share/java/xml-commons-apis.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/tools.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-salesforce.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-bootstrap.jar

BUILD FAILED
/usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/Salesforce Deploy Test/workspace/deploy script/build.xml:16: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:com.salesforce:deploy
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration.
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -/usr/share/ant/lib
        -/root/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument


Total time: 0 seconds
```

It seems that ant-salesforce.jar file it isn't found, but it appears listed in the output. Any ideas?

More info:

Permissions check

```
ls -al /usr/share/ant/lib
total 3412
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 feb 12 15:36 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root    4096 feb 12 09:49 ..
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      28 feb 12 09:49 ant-bootstrap.jar -> ../../java/ant-bootstrap.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      18 feb 12 09:49 ant.jar -> ../../java/ant.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      27 feb 12 09:49 ant-launcher.jar -> ../../java/ant-launcher.jar
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 3483648 feb 12 12:58 ant-salesforce.jar
```

Jar contents check:

```
...
com/salesforce/ant/BulkRetrieveTask.class
com/salesforce/ant/CompileAndTest$CodeNameElement.class
com/salesforce/ant/CompileAndTest$RunTestsElement.class
com/salesforce/ant/CompileAndTest.class
com/salesforce/ant/Configuration.class
com/salesforce/ant/ConnectionFactory.class
com/salesforce/ant/DeployTask$CodeNameElement.class
com/salesforce/ant/DeployTask.class
com/salesforce/ant/DescribeMetadataTask.class
com/salesforce/ant/ListMetadataTask.class
com/salesforce/ant/RetrieveTask$PackageManifestParser.class
com/salesforce/ant/RetrieveTask.class
com/salesforce/ant/SFDCAntTask.class
com/salesforce/ant/SFDCMDAPIAntTask.class
com/salesforce/ant/SFDCMDAPIAntTaskRunner.class
com/salesforce/ant/ZipUtil.class
com/salesforce/antlib.xml
...
```

antlib File contents (as expected):

```
<antlib>
    <typedef name="compileAndTest" classname="com.salesforce.ant.CompileAndTest"/>
    <typedef name="deploy" classname="com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask"/>
    <typedef name="retrieve" classname="com.salesforce.ant.RetrieveTask"/>
    <typedef name="bulkRetrieve" classname="com.salesforce.ant.BulkRetrieveTask"/>
    <typedef name="listMetadata" classname="com.salesforce.ant.ListMetadataTask"/>
    <typedef name="describeMetadata" classname="com.salesforce.ant.DescribeMetadataTask"/>
</antlib>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure it's the right jar? I know stupid question, but one never knows :-)

Comment: Not a stupid question. But I've double checked this too. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: I've reinstalled ant and now all seems to work OK. Weird thing.

Thanks for your support guys

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for sf:deploy is good.  Matches mine.

Check your project definition.  Are you setting the namespace of xmlns:sf to the right value?

Should be:

```
<project name="salesforce" default="deploy" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
```

You could also check the permissions of ant-salesforce.jar.

And then check that the jar is not corrupted

jar -tf ant-salesforce.jar

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've checked your the namespace settings and I have the same as you. The jar permissions are now 777 but the problem persists.

I've also checked the jar contents and the antlib file but all seems to be ok. I've updated the questions with this information.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, fixed it by changing the permission to the ant-salesforce.jar lib.

for the ones getting this issue it's worth checking if it isn't a permission issue on the lib.

Comment: Can you specify what permission you changed and how? What OS?

Comment: Where should we change the permission and exactly under which path the jar file ant-salesforce.jar is present ?